# Why should an authentication server and a gateway be two distinct components?

Tags: microservices, authentication

Why should I decouple an authentication server from a gateway in a micro services architecture ?

A clear drawback is the additional network load needed to query the auth server in each request.

Are there any clear benefits to justify this cost?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat Is it better now ?

Comment: @CapBaracudas, what is not clear is whether you've attempted to unify the components, or looked in to the implications for your project as to scalability and load concerns.  If you can demonstrate you've done some initial cost/benefit analysis here, and need help with a certain aspect of that then it makes for a better question, and more generally applicable to the audience here.

Comment: Congrats, you have realised that distributed computing is hard. So, why to go Microservices in the first place? Why don't we all go back to the monoliths?

Comment: The question is not so much why we should trasnmit to distributed computing but more on how.. :D and to be honest monoliths are harder. Not to make them work but to do anything with them afterwards .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage: A successful attack on your gateway doesn’t compromise your authentication server and vice versa.

And if both are inside containers running on the same physical server, network load is basically memcpy (running at > 10 GB/sec).

Comment: Thanks . Both are arguments I did not posses !